# Can gschem (gEDA) print special characters (aka other than the "micron" symbol µ)?

Tags: linux, special-characters

I prefer to show low resistance values as *2Ω2* rather than *2.2* in my schematics. However when I print schematics and that character occurs, the printed version has a space instead of the *omega* symbol. On the other hand it perfectly shows the "*micron*" (µ) symbol on prints so [I *guess*] gEDA is able to somewhat print UTF-8 characters.

As I'm running Linux I've already tried to check if my working font is responsible for the missing character on prints. So I've selected an omega symbol (i.e. «*U+2126*» in `gucharmap`) that is indeed supported by the font (*Cantarell*) — by the way that very character is supported by my system fonts so it is not font-specific. But it doesn't change anything, a space is still printed instead of the real ohm symbol.

So my question is: does gschem support special characters and which does it support besides the "*µ*"?